# Error message "The sms code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again" in OTP Firebase Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

Whenever I tried to login with phone number using firebase, I recieve OTP code through sms and when I submit the recieved code, an error is there saying:"The sms code has expired
If I use the emulator, this does not happen. Only when using the original device.

```
class FirebaseHelper {
  static String? _uid;
  static String get uid => _uid!;

  static FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;


  static fcmListeners() async {
    if (Firebase.apps.isEmpty) {
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
    }
  }

  static signInWithPhone(
      BuildContext context, String phoneNumber) async {
    try {
      await firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 15),
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
        verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) async {
          await firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
        },
        verificationFailed: (error) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content: Text(error.message.toString()),
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
              ),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 130,
                  right: 20,
                  left: 20),
            ),
          );
        },
        codeSent: (verificationId, forceResendingToken) {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => OtpPage(
                  verificationId: verificationId,
                  resendToken: forceResendingToken),
            ),
          );
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) {},
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text(e.message.toString()),
          behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
          ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 130,
              right: 20,
              left: 20),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

static verifyOtp({
    required BuildContext context,
    required String verificationId,
    required String userOtp,
    required Function onSuccess,
  }) async {
     PhoneAuthCredential creds = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
         verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: userOtp);
    try {
      User? user = (await firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(creds)).user;
      await AppSharedPreferences.setUserOtpLoggedIn(true);
      PhoneNumber dataPhoneNumber =
          PhoneNumber(phoneNumber: UserConstant.phoneNumber);
      await DatabaseHelper().insert('phoneNumber', dataPhoneNumber.toMap());
      print(user);
      if (user != null) {
        _uid = user.uid;
        onSuccess();
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
         SnackBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          content: Text(e.message.toString()),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

I realized, it seems like the OTP code sent has been used for verification by Android. So when I entered the OTP code from SMS, it was considered to have expired.

Maybe there is something I can do? Thank You.